# RewriteBase with 2 parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am working on a rewrite base file - and need to add an extra parameter

currently its reading like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /img/pins/
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ pins.php?n=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and that is fine as it comes out /img/pins/1
n=1

but I need to write the file to accomodate a new flag

so /img/pins/1/check

n=1
f=check

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /img/pins/
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ pins.php?n=$1&f=$2 [QSA,L]
```

^ but this current version indicates n=1/check f=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i undestand correctly. You need two group. If you want it will work with empty path or 1 and 2 groups, don't remove question sign after slash

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /img/pins/
RewriteRule  ^([^/]*)/?(.*)$ pins.php?n=$1&f=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule  ^(.*)\/(.*)$ pins.php?n=$1&f=$2 [QSA,L]
```

However if you know the first parameter is a number and the second one is alphanumeric I'd go for

```
RewriteRule  ^([0-9]+)\/([0-9a-z]+)$ pins.php?n=$1&f=$2 [QSA,L]
```

That would help a lot with potential parsing and injection issues